# Search Verticals (tabs) not visible in 2013 & results are unexpected

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I have configured search and created a site collection using search center template . Why cant i see the search verticals in OOTB ? like Videos,Conversation tabs etc

Also if i type the entire word only then the results are being returned . Eg - if i type "Superform" the results are returned . But if i type "uper" , no results are displayed .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you create an Enterprise Search Center or a Basic Search Center. Only the Enterprise template has the Search Verticals preconfigured. SharePoint Search uses word breaking for indexing. Your search for "uper" will not work. You could search for "Sup*" and find the content.

Comment: thx , 'Sup' doesnot return me results .

Comment: Did you add the asterisk?

Comment: Why i cant get results for "Sup" ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer "Why" questions, I didn't build the product. All I can say is it doesn't work that way. If "Sup" was a word stem like "teach" you will get results for "teacher" and "teaching" but "sup" is not a word root in English.

Comment: appreciate your response . But i dont get result for "Super" . . but yes , for asterisk i do get all required results.

Comment: In English, "sup" is not the root of "super", so it won't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the search verticals, you might want to try to check the `Search Settings` in `Site Settings` to see what all verticals are there.

As far the results are concerned, the search might be retrieving based on `exactly equals to` condition.